# SQL Server - Retrive Delete database Transaction log

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server- Multi User

I want to see the log of databases deleted and Userid who has executed the "Delete" transaction.

Comment: Would [How to view transaction logs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3462799/2545927) be of any help?

Comment: Same question was raised on SQL Exchange :

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/how-to-find-out-who-deleted-some-data-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

The default trace will contain database create/alter/delete events.  The query below will return the needed information if the action is still in the files.

```
SELECT 
     te.name AS EventName
    ,tt.StartTime
    ,tt.HostName
    ,tt.LoginName
    ,tt.ApplicationName
FROM sys.traces AS t
CROSS APPLY fn_trace_gettable(
    REVERSE(N'crt.gol' + SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.path), CHARINDEX(N'\', REVERSE(t.path)), 128)), default) AS tt
JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON
    te.trace_event_id = tt.EventClass
JOIN sys.trace_subclass_values AS tesv ON
    tesv.trace_event_id = tt.EventClass
    AND tesv.subclass_value = tt.EventSubClass
WHERE
    t.is_default = 1 --default trace
    AND tt.ObjectType = 16964; --database type
```